# Trying to get SPI running on RaspPi 3 (Loopback)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

cannot figure out how to do the loopback test from the spidev module.
Executing provided spidev_test.c file works. Not yet in Python.

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.loop = True
spi.open(0,0)

try:
    while True:
        spi.writebytes([0xAA, 0xFF])
        time.sleep(0.01)
        print(spi.readbytes(2))    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    spi.close()
```

Comment: I meant how to verify the SPI, so how to send a byte and simultaneously receive it.

Comment: `spi.writebytes([0xAA, 0xFF]); time.sleep(0.01); print(spi.readbytes(2))`

Comment: Gives me the error "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" at the time.sleep(0.01) line

Comment: done...all in the while loop. one more question: how can I write and read the spi simultaneously..
in my opinion the readbytes loses the written bytes because of the time.sleep

Comment: Nothing wrong, add a Link to `spidev_test.c file works`.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/linux/rpi-3.10.y/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c

From: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md (bottom)

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**: Gives the same output as written in xfer2 just because the function xfer2 returns the values that are given, so not really a confirmation of a working spi

Thats what `xfer` are supposed to do.
Does it differ from `spidev_test.c` output?
Use a unvailable `port` or `device` and you will fail.

---

> **Comment**: spi.loopback() missing

Have you checked the `spi.loop` Status?
Feel free to set `spi.loop = True`
Relevant: [Loopback_Testing](http://elinux.org/Jetson/TX1_SPI#Loopback_Testing)

---

You are looking something like this:

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
# spidev_test.c uses /dev/spidev1.1
spi.open(1,1) #use spi Port 1, device (CS) 1

while True:
    try:
        response = spi.xfer2([0xAA, 0xFF])
        print(response)
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        spi.close()
```

Comment: Gives the same output as written in xfer2 just because the function xfer2 returns the values that are given, so not really a confirmation of a working spi.
Plus: spi.loopback() missing

or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: @soderdaen: Updated my Answer